# Export PuTTY settings (or sessions) from a Linux to another Linux

Tags: linux, ssh, putty

I've been searching the internet for an answer for this question, but I found only answers for exporting from a Windows to another (using regedit).

Is it possible to export PuTTY sessions from a Linux machine to another and how to do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can find the sessions under (where `~` represents the user's home directory):

```
~/.putty/sessions/
```

Each session is a file in that directory, so you can copy the whole directory, or just individual sessions.

EDIT: Private key files, if used, are not stored within the session files, so they will also need to be copied from their original location.

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt and clear answer! The server I'm using is actually down now so I can not test this right now but will it grant me the same access I had in my other linux installation?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "same access".  When you copy the sessions from one computer to another, the sessions on the new computer will have all of the same settings as on the old one.  I've added a note about coping private keys.

Comment: Helped us fix Jenkins not being able to use SCP, whereas root could.